# how to create Facebook Access Token with ads_management permission

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

we used to have a working augmented system to login facebook and get&manage advertisement data. then we need to change the facebook account password of the user we used for login automatically in php. and old access token we used in PHP to login facebook is now not working.

I have tried to create a new access token with Graph API Explorer but I've got this error: `appsecret_proof validation`. then when i commented out this check and continue then I have recieved this error (line breaks added):

```
{"error":
    {"message":
        "(#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission \
            ads_management and an application that is whitelisted to \
            access the Ads API",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":294
    }
}
```

I almost don't know anything about facebook api how to use it.

Could you give me a detailed explanation of how i can create and access token with the `ads_management` right?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.0

Answer (score 0):

As Max points out, the Facebook documentation is the best source for detailed explanations of how to get access tokens and the ads_management extended permission. The [Facebook Ads API guide overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview) provides the specific details you request including the link to the [application form for receiving Ads API app approval](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access).

> The Ads API is a restricted platform which may only be accessed by whitelisted Apps.